# Best way to distribute an ISO? (open source, so must be free)

Tags: web-hosting

I want to distribute a LiveCD of my Open Source project.

- ~300MB ISO file.
- No revenue, so no money.
- Around 1000 downloads per month expected.

What is the best way to distribute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is http://sourceforge.net/, Its free and used by many open source developers.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a torrent tracker for an open licensed project, you could use http://www.clearbits.net/ - the same people that StackOverflow use for their data dumps.

Otherwise, as Imran points out, SourceForge will mirror it worldwide for you.

Comment: clearbits.net costs money even for free software content, if I understood well?

Comment: Hmmm, upon further investigation, this may now be the case. Check before proceeding!

Answer (score 2):

Submit it as a Bittorrent file and post your .torrent file.

Comment: That would suppose to have a server to serve the content, at least at first, right?